# How to check my ip is static or dhcp

Tags: networking

When I run `more interfaces` I get

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I am on wifi. How to konw my ip is static or dynamic? When run `ip addr` I get

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:d5:5e:78:64:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlx00e02d051a2d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:2d:05:1a:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.43.87/24 brd 192.168.43.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlx00e02d051a2d
       valid_lft 2283sec preferred_lft 2283sec
    inet6 2401:4900:4c6a:ba87:2348:3cc3:5ff9:337/64 scope global noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5cde:b91:60ef:2ee1/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I think ipv4 is dynamic, what about ipv6? Is it static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `ip addr` from a terminal window the output should tell you.  The line that starts with `inet` in the output will tell you.  Dynamic will say but Static will be blank. Plus, the line containing `valid_lft` and `preferred_lft` will show time remaining if dynamic. I have put some examples below.

DHCP or Dynamic IP Address:

```
$ ip addr
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:8d:5c:4f:12:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp3s0
    inet 10.0.0.100/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 28899sec preferred_lft 28899sec
```

Static IP Address:

```
$ ip addr
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:79:66:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.220/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I updated my question, please look it. Is ip6 static?

Comment: @JustineChacko When it comes to IPv6 that is a whole other story.  There are many things about it.  My guess is that the IPv6 that you are seeing is not coming from DHCP.  I do see a link-local address, but that is assigned to the interface even when a routeable IP is present.  There is so much information out there about IPv6, but I would say that the IPv6 you are seeing is not dynamic.  Are you using IPv6 for internet access?

Comment: @JustineChacko Looking at your output though, I see it has a link-local address assigned for IPv6 (starts with the `fe80`) which is assigned on every IPv6 interface even with a routeable IP address assigned.  The other IP looks like it is assigned like from a router as a reserved IP.  If you didn't assign it yourself in your config files chances are that came from your router.  My educated guess is that it is not static.

Comment: There seem to be exceptions (or are they related to the IPv6 difference?): with my Freebox router (in France), `ip addr` says `scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0  valid_lft 42426sec preferred_lft 42426sec` for my laptop's explicitly "dynamic" IP, but the `42426sec` (11.7 hours) and the IP stay the same since yesterday. Maybe it will change all of a sudden in the future, but for the moment I like this setting for my LAN samba shares.

Comment: @cipricus Not that I am aware of.  If you have a 24 hour release renew on your DHCP server the time checked yesterday should be the same time as today.  You can, however, see the time changing live by running `watch -n 1 ip addr` and you should see those seconds counting down when you have a dynamic IP.  Ctrl+C will break you out of the watch command.

Comment: @Terrance - Oh, I thought that a dynamic IP means that at the end of the 11 hours or so the IP would change! - With the command above I do see the `valid_lft` secs diminishing but what happens when it goes to zero is not necessarily that it changes: It takes a router reset or ISP setting, right? - But what do the seconds mean then?

Comment: @Terrance - After restarting the Freebox router the dynamic IP above didn't change. Excellent for my samba.

Comment: @cipricus The IP will not change as long as the DHCP server did not assign it to another device.  Chances are you don't have a lot of devices on your network so you shouldn't have an issue.  However, if the system is turned off when the timer on the DHCP lease expires, it will cause it so that the client doesn't respond back to the DHCP server requesting the IP address again and that can cause the DHCP server to release that IP to any other system requesting it, unless you have a reservation by MAC Address set on your DHCP server for that system.

Comment: @cipricus One other thing, because the DHCP server leases that IP address for the specified amount of time rebooting the client will not change the amount of time remaining on that IP address with the server. The client will still maintain that remaining time on it.  However, if you force a release and renew, the DHCP server will respect that and release and renew the IP with a new timer.  A command like `sudo dhclient -r -v eth0 && sudo dhclient -v eth0` should force a release and renew.  As long as the IP address in the DHCP server is not assigned to another device, you should be good.

Answer (score -1):

You couldn't find out static or not by working interface itself. dhcp or not is configged by some config script. On ubuntu, IP can normally configged by startup script or Network Manager daemon or newest netplan machine.

1. By startup script, you could checkout /etc/interfaces or
   /etc/interfaces.d/*** file
2. By NetworkManager daemon, you could use command nwcli to check the
   config.
3. By netplan machine, check /etc/netplan/* config files.